# wsSheetname change issue

Tags: excel, vba

I found some code online, but when I change it, it will not work.
The code is for filling pdf forms with Excel.

At the top of the code is:

```
    'Find the last row of data in sheet Write.
    With shWrite 'the sheet named Write
        .Activate
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
```

I have created another sheet named Test
When I change the sheetname from shWrite to shTest the code stops working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you `Set shTest = ...`? Or did you change the sheet *codename*?

Comment: Would help to show more of the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the tutorial from

https://myengineeringworld.net/2013/10/read-and-write-pdf-forms-from-excel-vba.html

This does not appear to have example sheets prior to running they seem to be embedded in the macro.

```
sheetPr codeName="shWrite"
```

So if you wish to alter the tutorial sheet names you may need to alter the macro or rename the sheets and macro components.

I dont have time to follow the full tutorial, that is for your learning, but suggest you watch for where and how to reuse for your own sheet names is defined.

Comment: Thanx, I will trie it

Answer (score 0):

I found I should rename the properties of the Test sheet.
Renamed (Name) to shTest
Renamed Name to Test

In the VBA code
replaced shWrite with shTest

the code works wonderful now.